# GAE Go perform additional actions on logout

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When a user logs out of a GAE app via the user.LogoutURL path, I want to perform additional actions when they log out.

How can I override that with a specific handler (like so: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/#Go_User_authentication_in_Go) and still perform the required logout actions? Or how can I detect a user is logging out and then perform the actions I want?

Comment: Have you tried adding a custom handler and redirecting to the logout url?

Comment: That's a pretty easy option actually, but that means two redirects. Which I suppose isn't all that bad on a logout. I'll try that approach for now until someone offers up a better one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do, is create your own logout handler, and redirect to the `user.LogoutURL`.

```
func logoutHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    // do what you want to do here.
    http.Redirect(w, r, users.LogoutURL(c))
}
```